# Inserting encapsuled object in firestore and goods practices

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

I have a question about to insert object in **firestore** in **angularfire**:

My object Person.ts

```
name: String
age: Number
//--constructor--
//--getters and setters--
```

if I do this, insert ok: (BUT is this good practice?)

```
[person.component.ts]
      this.db.collection("person").add({
              name: this.person.$nome,
              age: this.person.$email
          })
    ...
```

but if I try:

```
    [person.component.ts]
         this.db.collection("person").add({
                     Person: this.person
//or this this.person
                  })
```

I get this error in browser console:

**Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Person object (found in field Person)
    at new FirestoreError (error.js:149)
    at**

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem when saving a custom object, even though Google says it should be possible - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: I continue inserting with {key: values} way:                                              
        
  onsubmit() {    
    this.db.collection("user").add({
      name: this.form.get('name').value,
      email: this.form.getemail: ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore only accepts a JavaScript object embedded within a document if it is a “pure” object, this means you can't use custom objects while coding with TypeScript.

Change your code to:

```
this.db.collection("person").add(Object.assign({}, this.person));
```